# Remove Duplicate Node and calculate few fields and out put in tabular format

Tags: xslt

Need help to build XSLT. For the below XML, need to print records based on below calculations. Data in Text format.

Rules,

1. Cost need to be totaled for plan 1 and print on Employee record
2. For Coverage calculations if Coverages are (1,2 and 3 ) Print 4 for plan1, else print highest Number
3. Employee relation need to display as EMP (No data in XML for Employee Relation Field)
4. Record printing based on Relation. Record must display in following Order: Emp, Sp, CH ( Where applicable)
5. Keep leading Zeros in SSN field.

   `<Data> <Dataset> <Employee> <Name>Space Mark</Name> <Plan>1</Plan> </Employee> <Coverage>3</Coverage> <Cost>5<Cost> </Dataset> <Dataset> <Employee> <name>Space Mark</Name> <Plan>1</Plan> </Employee> <Coverage>3</Coverage> <Cost>3<Cost> <Dependent> <name>Jack</Name> <Plan>1</Plan> <relation>CH</Relation> </Dependent> <Dependent> <name>Micky</Name> <Plan>1</Plan> <relation>CH</Relation> </Dependent> </Dataset> <Dataset> <Employee> <name>Space Mark</Name> <Plan>1</Plan> </Employee> <Coverage>2</Coverage> <Cost>4<Cost> <Dependent> <name>Tom</Name> <Plan>1</Plan> <relation>SP</Relation> </Dependent> </Dataset> <Dataset> <Employee> <name>Space Mark</Name> <Plan>2</Plan> </Employee> <Coverage>4</Coverage> <Cost>7.50<Cost> <Dependent> <name>Tom</Name> <Plan>2</Plan> <relation>SP</Relation> </Dependent> <Dependent> <name>Jack</Name> <Plan>2</Plan> <relation>CH</Relation> </Dependent> <Dependent> <name>Micky</Name> <Plan>2</Plan> <relation>CH</Relation> </Dependent> </Dataset> </Data>`

**Expected Output:**
 `Name,Plan,Relation,Coverage,Cost Space Mark,1,Emp,4,000001200 Tom,1,SP,, Jack,1,CH,, Micky,1,CH,,`enter code here`
Space Mark,2,Emp,4,000000750
Tom,2,SP,,
Jack,2,CH,,
Micky,2,CH,,

`

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: Please ask a **specific** question about a difficulty you encountered when trying to accomplish this. Otherwise it looks like you're just looking for someone to do your work for you.